# How can I initialise the vector of vectors of ints?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a 2-D Vector (basically representing a graph with first column being the initial vertex and the second column being the final vertex), something like this, `vector<vector<int> > myvec`;

And I want to store something like this,

```
0 -> 1 2 
1 -> 2 3
2 -> 3 4
3 -> 4 5
5 -> 1 2
```

If I want to initialise `myvec`, that is, do something like this with the total number of rows (number of vertices) and then I can insert the second vertex at appropriate position, i.e. after initialisation (if I enter number of vertices as 6), I want it to look something like this,

```
0 ->
1 ->
2 ->
3 ->
4 ->
5 ->
```

And then I can insert the appropriate edge using,

```
myvec[startingvertex].push_back(endingvertex) // with starting vertex and ending vertex taken as input
```

How can I do it? Thanks!

Edit: I have:

```
class graph
{
    int vertices;
    vector<vector<int> > edges;
}
```

In the `main`, I do the following

```
int main (void)
{
    int i,n;
    cout<<"How many vertices do you wish to enter\n";
    cin>>n;
    graph *mygraph = new graph;
    mygraph->vertices = n;
    mygraph->edges // How can I initialise it here? 
   ......... // Rest of the code
}
```

Can you help me with the above commented question?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Comment: You should submit a new question instead of editing the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create myvec with 6 elements in it.
vector<vector<int> > myvec(6);

// Add items to the first item of myvec
myvec[0].push_back(1);
myvec[0].push_back(2);

// Add items to the sixth item of myvec
myvec[5].push_back(10);
myvec[5].push_back(25);
```

**Update**

Implement a constructor of `graph` as follows:

```
class graph
{
   public:
      grapah(int n) :  edges(n) {}

      vector<vector<int> > edges;
};
```

And use it as:

```
graph *mygraph = new graph(n);
```

You don't need the member variable `vertices` since `edges.size()` is the number of vertices.

Comment: Can the size be variable? That is, something like, `int v; cin>>v; vector<vector<int> > myvec(v);`?

Comment: @JohnLui, yes the size can be a variable. It is a run time parameter.

Comment: @JohnLui, I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: can you please answer the edit of the question? It's similar, but I am not exactly sure how can I do it as part of a class? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
myvec.resize(NUMBER_OF_VERTICES);
```

Then you can:

```
myvec[startingvertex].push_back(endingvertex);
```

To fill your vector.